# Angular 2. Recuperar actualización del Servicio al que estoy suscrito en componente B en cada click de componente A

Tags: angular

Tengo un componente A desde donde lanzo un evento click y envío el código al servicio:

```
    <button type="button" (click)="loadExpedientesFrame(siniestro.codigo)">
      enviar
    </button>

      loadFrame(codigo: string): void {
        this.expedientesService.cargarExpediente(codigo)
          .subscribe((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          });
      }
```

El servicio lo recibe y recupero los datos del backend correctamente, me muestra en consola cada vez que hago click y cambio el parámetro:

```
      cargarFrame(cosin: string) {
        const url = `${base_url}/frame/${cosin}`;
        return this.http.get<Modelo[]>(url, this.headers).pipe(
          map((resp: any) => {
            console.log('Servicio', resp.expedientes);
            return resp.expedientes;
          })
        );
      }
```

Desde el componente B estoy suscrito al servicio y recupero la lectura por default, es decir todo:

```
       ngOnInit(): void {
          this.loadFrame();
        }

        loadFrame() {
          this.miServicio.cargarFrame(this.cosin)
            .subscribe((expedientes: any) => {
              console.log('Destino', resp.expedientes);
              return this.expedientes = expedientes;
            });
        }
```

[image: en cada click recupero la lectura adecuada segun parametro]

El problema es que necesito que el componente B me muestre el cambio cada vez que el servicio recibe un parámetro nuevo en el click del component A.

Comment: A ver si me entero: `B` es un componente padre de `A`, tienes un botón en `A` y quieres que por cada vez que hay un click en `A`, aparezcan cambios en `B`. Pero dónde está inyectado el servicio, en `A`, en `B`, o en los dos?

Comment: Necesitas que el componente B esté suscrito a un observable que emite un evento cada vez que A hace una consulta

Comment: B y A son componentes independientes, pero A envía el parámetro al servicio y B lo recoge de éste. La finalidad es que B esté escuchando siempre los cambios del servicio ocasionados por A @DavidDPG

Comment: @rafa_pe entonces te recomiendo que: 
1- actualices la pregunta explicando cómo se comunican componentes y servicio, es importante en éste contexto ya que hay varias maneras de actuar según cómo esté montada la arquitectura
2- le eches un ojo a https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject, que creo que es lo que necesitas para mantener una comunicación bidireccional entre dos componentes con un servicio en medio